# How to write a query to return daily returning users?

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a very simple table `phone_calls` with these columns:

```
id, timestamp, phone_number
```

How to write a query which returns **a daily count of returning users**? It should have two columns:

```
Date, Number of Returning Users
```

**Returning user:**

A returning user for any given day D is the one, who has called at least once before D.

A user who has called multiple times on D, but hasn't called before D won't be counted as a returning user.

**UPDATE**

So here is what I have tried:

```
SELECT DATE(timestamp) AS date, COUNT(DISTINCT phone_number) AS user_count
FROM phone_calls
WHERE phone_number IN (SELECT phone_number FROM phone_calls GROUP BY phone_number HAVING COUNT(consumer_id) > 1)
GROUP BY DATE(timestamp)
```

But it's not a correct solution, because it doesn't comply with definition of Returning User mentioned above.

**What I am struggling with?**

For any given date, how do I filter out those phone numbers from the count, who never dialed in before that day?

Comment: Sounds like homework. What have you tried already? What, exactly, are you stuck on?

Comment: Could you show us your attempt and why it isn't working? If you want us to do all the work, you've either misunderstood stack overflow or [you're actually looking to pay a freelancer to do it for you](http://www.freelancer.com).

Comment: Aren't you guys too quick to judge? It isn't a homework. I'm writing some reports and actual table is much more complex. I've simplified the problem here so I can communicate it here easily.

Comment: Can you please help me understand why -1?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    DATE(timestamp) AS date,
    COUNT(DISTINCT phone_number) AS     user_count
FROM 
    phone_calls pc
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM phone_calls pc1
    WHERE 
        pc1.phone_number = pc.phone_number AND
        DATE(pc1.timestamp) < DATE(pc.timestamp)
    )
GROUP BY DATE(pc.timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Updated try this query

```
 Select date(pc.timestamp) AS RDate ,count(*)  
from phone_calls pc INNER JOIN phone_calls pcc
on pcc.phone_number=pc.phone_number 
and date(DATE_ADD(pcc.timestamp, INTERVAL -1 DAY))= DATE (pc.timestamp)  group by DATE (pc.timestamp);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't comply with the definition of Returning Users above.

Comment: The updated query is showing results way off then expected. For example, in data that we have, total phone calls we received in a particular day are 471. But your query is showing a count of 1672 for that day.